# How to use SPARQL in DBpedia

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I have learned SPARQL to do query over DBpedia, but since I finished the course, I found that I am not able to write query on https://dbpedia.org/sparql, because I do not know the the RDF format for the page.

I want a link for learning query over Virtuoso, or a way to find the RDF source of DBpedia.

Comment: The DBpedia Wiki is [here](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/) and the ontology can be downloaded [here](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-10/dbpedia_2016-10.nt) Anything else is up to you, especially as you already "learned sparql" and in addition, nobody here knows what exactly you want to query for. But as the ontology contains the schema, you should be able to continue.

Comment: By the way, the phrase "the RDF format" is a bit misleading because this is not what you're asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might start with a [resource description page on DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/page/DBpedia)...

Or the [Facet Browser](http://dbpedia.org/fct/)...

Or the [iSPARQL graphical query builder](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/)...

For certain, this question is too broad for anyone to answer more usefully.